# Differential equation - stuck on how to proceed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x - 2y}{3x - 2y}$

I would just like a hint/suggestion as to how to proceed. I'm just completely stuck as to how to tackle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a homogeneous differential equation. Therefore, you can substitute $y=vx$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}x+v$ ($v$ is a function of $x$) to obtain:
$$\frac{dv}{dx}x+v=\frac{2x-2vx}{3x-2vx}=\frac{2-2v}{3-2v}$$
Which is separable.